# How to set the response content type in a Spring controller that returns a unit (void)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, kotlin

I have a controller in my Spring project that doesn't return anything. Its response type in the **openAPI** doc is `text`, but I want to change it to `application/json`. I already added `produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE]` to my `@RequestMapping` annotation, but it just works for functions returning a value. The only way I found is to add this return statement, but I am going to find a general solution.

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build()
```

What is the best solution?

Comment: if your response doesn't return anything you shouldn't be returning a 200 but a 204 imho. Then you also don't need to set the content type since there is no content.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your response doesn't return anything you shouldn't be returning a 200 but a 204. Then you also don't need to set the content type since there is no content.

Comment: Yes, I added this annotation for the 204 status code. @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)